# How can I find using a pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a database table having records like:

```
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Mon1
Mon2
Tue1
Wed1
Thu1
Thu2
Fri1
Fri2 
...
```

I want to select all those records which have integer in the value; like Mon1, Fri2 etc. Using MySQL, how can I get it done using Regex or Wildcard?

Comment: well what effort have you made?

Comment: How does your table look like? Use `DESCRIBE`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), for example:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE col1 RLIKE '[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME RLIKE '[0-9]'
```

Now consider this:

```
expr RLIKE pat
```

Performs a pattern match of a string expression `expr` against a pattern `pat`. The pattern can be an extended regular expression. Returns 1 if `expr` matches `pat`; otherwise it returns 0. If either `expr` or `pat` is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`. `RLIKE` is a synonym for `REGEXP`, provided for mSQL compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME RLIKE '[0-9]$'
```

The '$' char is important if you want to select entries that end with a number, if you want to make sure there is a word before the number consider using :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME RLIKE '^[a-z]+[0-9]$'
```